# author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=False) trouble

Tags: django, foreign-keys, author

I have a table where I save data(description, x, y, result and creation date) and until now everything works.
I thought then to add a column with the author for each saved line eg:

**DES| X | Y | RESULT |CREATION DATE| AUTHOR |**

```
hi | 3| 1 |   4    |  24/02/2015     | username |
```

then I added in models.py auth:

> ```
> from django.db import models
> from django.utils import timezone
> from simpleapp.oper import add_divide
> from django.conf import settings
>
>
> class ElementiTab(models.Model):
>     author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=False)
>     des = models.CharField(max_length=30)
>     x = models.FloatField()
>     y = models.FloatField()
>     res = models.FloatField(default=0)
>     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
>
>     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.res = add_divide(self.x, self.y)
>         super(ElementiTab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
>
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.des
> ```

UPDATE:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ElementiTab

class  ElementiTabForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model =  ElementiTab
        fields = ('des', 'x', 'y')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def tabval(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    valori = ElementiTab.objects.filter().order_by('-created_date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ElementiTabForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            form.save()

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = ElementiTabForm()

    return render(request, 'simpleapp/simpleapp.html', {'form': form, 'valori': valori})

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def delete(request, id):
    valori_to_delete = get_object_or_404(ElementiTab, pk=id).delete()
    return redirect(tabval)
```

simpleapp.html

```
{% extends 'registration/base_reg.html' %}
    {% block title %}SimpleApp-tabval{% endblock %}
    {%block content%}       



             <h4>TABELLA CON DATI</h4>






<form action="/simpleapp/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="LIST" />
  </form>
<form action="/simpleapp/" method="DELETE">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="canc" value="RESET" />
 </form>

  <br />
  <br />        

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr class="info">
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> NOME</td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> X </td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> Y </td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> RISULTATO </td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> DATA CREAZIONE </td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> AUTORE </td>
                            {% for elementi in valori %}
                                <div class="elementi">
                                    <tr>

                                    <td>{{elementi.des}}</td> 
                                    <td>{{elementi.x}}</td>
                                    <td>{{elementi.y}}</td>
                                    <td>{{elementi.res}}</td>
                                    <td>{{elementi.created_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{elementi.author}}</td>
                                    <td width="1%">
                                    {% if user.is_superuser %}
                                        <a href="/delete/{{elementi.id}}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger disabled" role="button"><span style='font-size: small'>Only Admin</span></a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                </div>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                    </div>



{% endblock content %}
```

The fact is that the admin page displays a drop-down menu from which I (as administrator) can *choose* one of the registered user and so I add them both in the table of my app and in the db.

How can I make this process automatic?  I.e. after the login, you put data in the table  and once saved the data, also  the username is saved and should not be the administrator to set it.

I searched a similar question here but I have not found one to help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answere, i misenderstood your question.

Change this in your view

```
    if form.is_valid():
        # Creating the object without commiting to database
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        # Setting the user from request
        obj.author = request.user
        # Commiting to the database
        obj.save()
```

Comment: I updated my question with my code... I think I did as suggested by the django documents but I'm not sure if it is the same thing that you are think about.

Comment: Thanks,  now it work! Could you explain why you need to do these  extra steps?

Comment: You do not have the current logged-in user in the form, first we create an object from the form, then we set the user, finnaly we commit it to the database.